# How to unwrap a tunneled packet in iptables/netfilter and process the tunneled packet

Tags: iptables, tunneling, netfilter

I have a specific question regarding the Linux netfilter/iptables interaction.
Let's say I have an IP packet P1 inside of another IP packet P2 (that is, P1 is tunneled).

Now, the question is as follows:
Is it possible to examine a specific header field of the "outer" packet P2 (for example, the MAC source address), and then send the "inner" packet P1 to a certain iptables chain based on the inspected field?

As a small example:
Let's say, I have 3 chains in the FORWARD table, C1 to C3.
Now, if the MAC source address of P2 has the value 17, I want to send the "inner" packet P1 to C1.
If the MAC source address is 28, I want to send P1 to C2.
Otherwise, I want to send P2 to C3.

I am absolutely unsure if it is possible to do so in iptables.
Maybe this could be also be achieved by hooking a bit of C code to a specific netfilter hook.

I know this is some kind of a weird use case, but I am just curious.

Thanks in advance!